# Inserting into temp table from view is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, temp-tables

I am using different temp tables in my query.  When I execute the query below

```
 select * from myView
```

It takes only 5 seconds to execute.

but when I execute

```
select * into #temp from myView
```

It takes 50 seconds (10 times more than above query).

We  migrated from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2. Before in SQL 2000 both of the query takes same time but in SQL Server 2008 it takes 10 times more to execute.

Comment: How are you measuring the results of `select * from myView`?  If you are looking for when rows first start appearing, that is wrong.  You have to wait until all rows are there for a valid comparison.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes i am checking execution time at the end of the execution when the query finished executing.

Comment: What happens if you define the temp table first then insert, e.g. `CREATE TABLE #Temp (...) INSERT #Temp (...) SELECT * FROM MyView`. Can you post the execution plan for each query?

Comment: @GarethD i tried the approach as you suggested but it also takes the same time as select * int #temp from myview.

Comment: And the execution plans?

Comment: @GarethD u have to wait at least 10 hours as i am out of office and i haven't the access of Database.

Comment: Does `tempdb` located on a media, which is different than that of the database containing `myView`?

Comment: Try throwing option(recompile) on the end of the query. If it fixes the issue, a bad plan needs to be purged from the cache. Also, have you updated stats since upgrading servers?

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but as I had a similar issue (though on SQL Server 2014) and resolved it in a way which I have not seen on any readily available resource, thought I would share in hopes of it being helpful to someone else.

I had a similar situation: a view I had created was taking 21 seconds to return its complete result set, but would take 10+ minutes (at which point I stopped the query) when I converted it into a `SELECT..INTO`  The `SELECT` was a simple one, with no joins and no predicates.  My hunch was that the optimizer was altering the original plan based on the additional `INTO` statement which did not simply pull the data set as in the first instance, then perform the `INSERT`, but instead altered it in a way to run very sub-optimally.

I first tried an `OPENQUERY`, attempting to force the result set to be generated first, then inserted into the temp table.  Total running time for this method was 23 seconds, obviously much closer to the original `SELECT` time.  Following this, I returned to my original `SELECT..INTO` query and added an `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` hint to try to replicate the `OPENQUERY` behavior.  This seemed to have done the trick and the time was on par with the `OPENQUERY` method, 23 seconds.

I don't have enough time at the moment to compare the query plans, but as a quick and dirty option if you run into this issue, you can try:

```
select * into #temp from myView option (force order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would check the Execution Plan for your command. there may be an overhead on a sort or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your tempdb database is in trouble. May be slow I/O, fragmentation, broken RAID etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an order by clause  in your select statement such as `select * from myView order by col1` before inserting into temp table? If there is an order by,  that slows down insertion into temp table heavily. If that is the case, remove order by while the insertion happens and order after the insertion happened  like

```
select * 
into #temp
from myView
```

then apply order by

```
 select * from #temp order by col1
```